# 3-dof of a 3d plane

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

Degrees of freedom of a plane if $R^3$ is confuse me. I think ax+by+cz+d=0 has a 4 Dof, but it has a 3 Dof in Multiple View Geometry of Mr. Zisserman . Is the reason of 3 Dof caused by homogeneous coordinates?

1. why plane has a 3Dof
2. Is the reason of 3Dof caused by homogenous coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you can solve for one of the variables. In your case: $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$
$$\rightarrow cz=-ax-by-d$$
$$\rightarrow z=\frac{-a}{c}x+\frac{-b}{c}y+\frac{-d}{c}$$
From here, we can just chose to rename those coefficients. If we can chose any value for a, b, c, and d, then it's no different than choosing 3 numbers. $$z=Ax+By+C$$ where $A, B, C$ are any real number.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand it now!